# Android Vector fillColor not changing with DayNight Mode

Tags: android, android-layout, themes

I defined color resources for Day and Night theme using values-night qualifier

values/colors.xml

```
<color name="icon_color">#282C3C/color>
```

values-night/colors.xml

```
<color name="icon_color">#FFFFFF/color>
```

I've vector drawable which uses color resource from theme values

```
    android:fillColor="@color/icon_color"
```

I set this drawable using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/wp_ic_camera"` without any background or tint values and it uses `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.context, drawableRes)` in databinding to set the drawable

Users can choose the app theme to Light/Dark or System mode in App preference I update the theme using

```
   val nightMode = when (theme) {
            AppTheme.DARK -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
            AppTheme.LIGHT -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            AppTheme.SYSTEM -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
        }

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode)
```

The issue is when device theme is Dark and App theme is set to Light it follows System theme for drawable colors

Comment: Remove `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Does it also do the same thing in the opposite situation (ie: Day mode and App theme set to dark?)

Comment: I'm guessing that the image is cached, so that when you change the theme you may need to set the images again.

Comment: did you solve the issue? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I see this as well. I moved my `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` call to being the first line in the `Application.onCreate()` but I'm still getting the wrong colors on startup.